# Verify JWT Token Signature

Tags: ios, swift, jwt, rsa, vapor

I am currently developing a Swift backend using Vapor. My iOS client uses the new iOS 13 feature "Sign in with Apple". When the user signs in I get an identity token (access token) which is a valid JWT token signed by Apple. This is send to the server in all ongoing communication to authenticate some routes the server provides.

On the server I'd like to validate that the sent token was indeed signed by Apple and is not specifically crafted by some malicious user by verifying the token signature. Apple provides a HTTP endpoint to retrieve the public key to do this: [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/signinwithapplerestapi/fetch_apple_s_public_key_for_verifying_token_signature).

However what I am not sure about how often I have to query this endpoint to retrieve the modulus and exponent from the API and build the public key to then verify the signature. **Is it sufficient enough to query this once and store the public key on the server to use this or would I need to query the HTTP endpoint in my middleware before verifying the signature (for every protected route)?**

Basically I am not sure whether the modulus and exponent will change from time to time.

Comment: https://jwt.io has a list of the libs for JWT verification for every popular language.

Comment: Why should the public key change?

Comment: @user28434 I know how to verify the signature, I am not sure about how often the public key could possibly change.

Comment: @LutzHorn I am not sure. Since the keys are out of my control I wanted to act cautiously, since when the key changes my server would not work any longer since all tokens couldn't be verified. However if I just can generate the key once and use it on my server this would be fantastic since this means no unnecessary http requests and reduced overhead for me.

Comment: If you use the Apple service, you have to use their public key. So what do you mean by 'generate the key once'? If you don't control the service issuing the JWT, you don't control the keys.

Comment: With 'generate the key once' I meant to generate the public key based on the modulus and exponent the API provides (see link in the question to the apple documentation above).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do this:

- fetch the public key once, store it on your server
- a request comes in, try to verify the signature using the stored public key
- if this fails, fetch the public key again, store it
- try to verify the signature a second time

This would allow you to know about a changed public key as soon as it is necessary.

Comment: Well this is obviously a great approach to the problem. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Just an additional point, let's say there is ten users have their JWT1s signed with key1. And then apple changes their key to key2. And then say ten other users get their JWT2s signed with key2 (at this point you still have key1 in your system). 
Say now that a user uses JWT2, then your verification will fail, you will fetch the public key from apple and try again, which will check out. Now say ten users send you JWT1, that means that you will end up fetching from apple 10 times and failing each time.
Hence, you may want to store all the various keys that you get from apple in your DB itself